# Replace values in one df from another on an ID col based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

```
Input:
d1 = {'col1': ['a','b','c','d'], 'col2': [1,2,3,4]}
d2 = {'col1': ['a','b','c'], 'col2': [0,3,4]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(d1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(d2)

Desired Output:
d3 = {'col1': ['a','b','c','d'], 'col2': [1,3,4,4]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(d3)
```

So I'd like to replace the values in df1 using 'col1' as the primary key with values from df2 only if the value is greater. The 2 dataframes are not the same size.

Comment: What would be the output if the two inputs where swapped? Or are all keys of df2 always in df1?

Comment: No I'm only interested in replacing the keys under the condition in df1

Comment: Sorry, this is still unclear, so there can be extra keys in df2 but you don't want them? Check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70193594/16343464)

Comment: Yes. I only want to replace values for the keys in df1 if they meet the condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is an idea using `clip` as a lower bound of the `map` of the values from `df2` to `df1['col1']`

```
df1['col3'] = df1['col2'].clip(lower=df1['col1'].map(df2.set_index('col1')['col2']))
print(df1)
#   col1  col2  col3
# 0    a     1     1
# 1    b     2     3
# 2    c     3     4
# 3    d     4     4
```

Comment: Nice. Is there a way to explicitly use a conditional statement? ie based on a '>'? Just to make it more versatile, ie... only replace the value if the value in the second column is > 5?

Comment: @chicagobeast12 one way is in the map, select only the values above the threshold oin df2, like `...map(df2.set_index('col1')['col2'].loc[lambda x: x>5])`

Comment: Picking yours as best answer since you were technically right but I found a way to implement the conditional statement without the resulting df returning nan values for keys that didn't map. The following works great: df1['col2'] = np.where(df1.['col2']<=3, df1['col1'].map(df2.set_index('col1')['col2']),df1['col2'])

Comment: @chicagobeast12 glad you found a way :)

Answer (score 0):

You can `concat` and get the `max` per row:

```
df1['col2'] = pd.concat([df1['col2'], df2['col2']], axis=1).max(1)
```

Output:

```
  col1  col2
0    a   1.0
1    b   3.0
2    c   4.0
3    d   4.0
```

*NB. This works with an arbitrary number of dataframes as input*

Answer (score 0):

Using the update function you can change a dataframe's column with some column of another dataframe. The logic of its greater can be done with a merge with the appropriate merge type:

```
dm= df1.merge(df2,on="col1").query("col2_x<col2_y").set_index("col1")[["col2_y"]].rename(columns={"col2_y":"col2"})
df1.set_index("col1", inplace=True)
df1.update(dm)
df3= df1.reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

Let us do append then `groupby`

```
out = df1.append(df2).groupby('col1',as_index=False).max()
  col1  col2
0    a     1
1    b     3
2    c     4
3    d     4
```

Comment: Instead of max(), is there a way to explicitly use a conditional statement? ie based on a '>'